# Callback function not holding onto local variable value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function

I probably am munging my terms pretty badly, so if you know the right way to refer to the value 'a' inside a function like:

```
var a = 10;
function addA(b){
  return b + a;
}
```

Let me know.

Anyway, long story short, I want to modify a variable inside $scope, after a callback returns, with a value. This is what I'm doing:

```
function fetchFromAPIs(_scope){
  if (navigator.geolocation){

    var foo = function(position){
      var scope = _scope;
      getPosition(position, scope);
    }
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(foo);
  }
  else{
    $(body).prepend("<span>Geolocation is not supported by this browser.</span>");
  }
}

function getPosition(position, scope){
  scope.weather = 'foo';
  scope.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
  scope.longitude = position.coords.longitude;
  getCityCountry(scope);
  getWeather(scope);
}

angular.module('app', [])
.controller('weatherController', function($scope){

  function init(){
    fetchFromAPIs($scope);
  }

  init();
});
```

Yet, $scope.weather is not getting updated. But if I comment out needing position inside getPosition, and call foo('') inside fetchFromAPIs($scope), the $scope.weather value gets updated just fine.

What on earth is happening? And is there a better Angular-approved way to do this? Thinking of giving up and just using jQuery to set my fetched values on the page...

Comment: You replace the link of `$scope` inside your `fetchFromAPIs`. Stop doing that and pass it as a reference, then everything will be fine

Comment: I believe you're problem is `var foo = function(position){
      var scope = _scope; //local only to the function, you want to change the global variable. remove var
      getPosition(position, scope);
    } ` Remove var from that function call so it references the global version.

Comment: Where / how do you test that `$scope.weather` is set?

Comment: I added a $scope.$watch for "weather" in my controller, which will do whatever I ask (I had it console.log the new value)

Answer (score -1):

I believe your problem is

```
var foo = function(position){
  var scope = _scope;
  getPosition(position, scope);
}
```

Change it to:

```
var foo = function(position){
   scope = _scope; //reference global variable and not local.
  getPosition(position, scope);
}
```

Comment: What makes you think there is a global `scope` variable?

Comment: The fact that scope is an argument passed to the init function, it has to exist before the call and outside the functions.